# Can't rebuild indexes via EF ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have the following script to rebuild indexes:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fillfactor INT

SET @fillfactor = 80

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])+'.['+name +']' AS TableName
    FROM sys.tables

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @TableName + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@fillfactor) + ')'
    EXEC (@sql)

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

I have other scripts that run in the same manner as this one.

When I execute this in the following manner:

```
var sql = ResourceUtilities.ReadResourceContent("rebuild_indexes.sql");
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'TableCursor'.

The implementation details of `ReadResourceContent` are irrelevant - I am running other arbitrary SQL with this and it works fine.

Why is this happening and what needs to change?

Comment: What SQL Server version do you execute this on?

Comment: an aside: It is good practice to consider the acutal fragmentation before invoking a rebuild

Comment: @ErikEJ - Azure SQL - and absolutely.  This is a V1 where we have it running every two weeks since that approximates the frequency at which defragmentation reaches levels needing attention.

Comment: Are you able to run the script via SSMS against your Azure database?

Comment: @ErikEJ Yes I am.

Comment: @SB2055 make sure you have a line break between `CLOSE ableCursor` and `DEALLOCATE TableCursor`, this would mess the parsing of the script. inspect all the special characters on the script with a good text editor.

Comment: @RicardoC I still get `Incorrect syntax near 'TableCursor'.`.  This is easily reproduced by using DbContext to run the script above, line breaks aplenty.

Comment: You should at least try terminating all lines with a semicolon. Also, while probably not the issue, it would be best to not mix VARCHAR and NVARCHAR. Since you are dealing with identifiers, all should be NVARCHAR and all string literals prefixed with `N`. On a side note, in most cases, especially for tables with an Identity column, a FILLFACTOR of 80 is horrible, and you should be using 100. Using NEWID then start with 90 and lower only if necessary. For NEWSEQUENTIALID use 100.

Comment: Off-topic: don't reinvent the wheel: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqlemea/2016/07/03/how-to-maintain-azure-sql-indexes-and-statistics/

Comment: @srutzky with semicolons everywhere they can possibly go, I get `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.`

Comment: @GertArnold - It's not clear to me what that solution handles.  Do I run that once and then forget about it, or do I have further responsibility?  It appears I have to go out of my way to schedule this with az functions - I already have scheduling frameworking in place running the above.  It looks like two wheels are being made for different models.

Comment: A `GO` is a batch separator that is only known to client apps (such as SSMS). You can't use it in Dynamic SQL. Remove it. It's also not in your script above, else I would have mentioned it ;-)

Comment: @srutzky - whoops, that was part of my most recent debugging.  Adding semicolons did the trick.  Feel free to make an answer and I'll award the goods :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least try terminating all lines with a semicolon. While rarely required (only two instances I know of are statements prior to `THROW` statements, which were introduced in SQL Server 2012, and prior to CTEs), it was officially noted as a best practice as of the release of SQL Server 2005.

One of the benefits of terminating statements / queries with semicolons is that SQL Server will have an easier time parsing the query batch when there are issues such as inconsistent line-endings, which is likely the root cause of the issue here. I am guessing that the root cause is inconsistent line-ending because you are able to run the script via SSMS against your Azure database. If the semicolons were required on Azure SQL Database, then it would have produced an error even when running via SSMS. Most likely SSMS made the line-endings consistent before submitting the batch, something that running via .NET code would not have done automatically for you.

Other notes:

- It would be best to not mix `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` (even though Datatype Precedence will convert it all to `NVARCHAR` in the end) . Since you are dealing with identifiers (i.e. table names, which are `sysname` type in the Database, which is an alias for `NVARCHAR(128)` ), ideally all should be `NVARCHAR` and all string literals prefixed with `N`.
- In most cases, especially for tables with an Identity column, a `FILLFACTOR` of 80 is horrible, and you should be using 100. Whn using `NEWID()` then start with 90 and lower only if necessary. For `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` use 100.
- When declaring cursors, if the query is referencing real tables instead of temporary tables, then use the `STATIC` keyword so as to not lock the base table(s). And *usually* not a bad idea to also use the following keywords: `LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY`.

End result should look as follows:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname, -- system alias for NVARCHAR(128)
        @SQL NVARCHAR(500),
        @FillFactor TINYINT; -- value cannot be < 0 or > 100 anyway

SET @FillFactor = 100; -- or 90 if using NEWID() for Clustered Index

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR STATIC LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.[object_id]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(st.[name]) AS [TableName]
    FROM   sys.tables st;

OPEN TableCursor;

FETCH NEXT
FROM  TableCursor
INTO  @TableName;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'ALTER INDEX ALL ON '
               + @TableName
               + N' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = '
               + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(3), @FillFactor)
               + N')';

    EXEC (@SQL);

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM  TableCursor
    INTO  @TableName;
END;

CLOSE TableCursor;
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
```

Comment: Would you recommend to use `QUOTENAME(st.name)` instead of `N'.[' + st.name + N']'` here?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I don't usually use that, but then again, I have never come across someone embedding a `]` character into an object name ;-). But yes, a good idea. I will update with it. Thanks :)